# PouchDB as a real live data tool for different collections

Tags: couchdb, publish-subscribe, pouchdb

I'm thinking of using PouchDB as a solution to automatically update comments that are submitted by users on papers.

It should mimic the behavior of a subscribe/publish service. Whenever someone submits a comment in his client, the list of comments on an other client should automatically update.

This is possible using PouchDB as described in the getting started guide:

```
var db = new PouchDB('paper');
var remoteCouch = 'http://user:pass@mname.iriscouch.com/paper';

function sync() {      
  var opts = {live: true};
  db.replicate.to(remoteCouch, opts, syncError);
  db.replicate.from(remoteCouch, opts, syncError);
}
```

The app holds different papers, each with their own comments. When using PouchDB as my publish/subscribe service, I have these questions:

- Is it a good idea to use PouchDB this way?
- If I only want to sync the comments of the current paper a user is working on, should I create a new database for each paper? (This would also mean I would lose the possibility to query for example all the users comments in all the papers from a single database)
- Is there a way to only sync a part of the database? This way I could still use the database to hold all the comments even for different papers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, PouchDB works fine for real-time stuff. It doesn't use web sockets, but it uses long-polling, which is fast enough for most use cases.

It sounds like you probably should create a separate database for each paper, assuming you want to restrict access on a per-paper basis. CouchDB authentication is kinda tricky, but basically if you want to control read access, you can either give users full read access or zero read access to an entire database. [There's a writeup here](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication#couchdb-authentication-recipes).

Also don't worry about creating thousands of databases; a "database" is cheap in CouchDB.

The only other thing I would advise is that maybe you would like the [relational-pouch plugin](https://github.com/nolanlawson/relational-pouch), because then you could easily set up a relational-style database with a "paper" type and a "comment" type.

Comment: If I would use validation functions to restrict writing comments to papers (reading comments does not need to be restricted), would it be possible to use the ```filter```option from the ```PouchDB.replicate(source, target, [options])```method to selectively filter which parts of the database are synced?

Comment: Sure, filter functions can allow you to replicate any subset of the database. I'm just pointing out that, if your concern is security, then filter functions won't protect a database from someone reading data they're not supposed to.

Comment: I'm writing a sync directive in AngularJS using PouchDB. Whenever an object of my database changes somewhere, it is updated. To do this, I'm using ```$scope.$watch```. The only problem I have now is that when an object changes and a save it to the database, the ```_rev```field changes as well, resulting in an infinite update loop :) Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: First off, such questions are probably better in the Freenode #pouchdb IRC channel than here. :) We can respond and iterate quicker.
Second, if you get stuck writing your angular directive, there are a handful of Angular libraries for Pouch. I've listed them [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63e50100ca36d06124ad).
Third, if you update the doc for every user keystroke, your history will grow [far too fast](http://pouchdb.com/2014/09/07/pouchdb-3.0.5.html)!
Fourth, my solution would be to create a sub-doc and then only watch that. e.g. `{_rev: 'foo', data: {...}}`